# Converting list to aggregated list

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a list like this:

```
date, type
29-5-2017, x
30-5-2017, x
31-5-2017, y
1-6-2017, z
2-6-2017, z
3-6-2017, y
28-5-2017, y
29-5-2017, z
30-5-2017, z
31-5-2017, y
1-6-2017, z
2-6-2017, z
3-6-2017, x
29-5-2017, x
30-5-2017, z
31-5-2017, z
1-6-2017, y
2-6-2017, x
3-6-2017, z
4-6-2017, y
```

How would I create an aggregated version of this list? So I get each date only once, and see how many of each type there are on a given date.

Like this:

```
date, no._of_x, no._of_y, no._of_z
28-5-2017, 0, 1, 0
29-5-2017, 2, 0, 1
30-5-2017, 1, 0, 2
31-5-2017, 0, 2, 1
1-6-2017, 0, 1, 2
2-6-2017, 1, 0, 2
3-6-2017, 1, 1, 1
4-6-2017, 0, 1, 0
```

Comment: And your question is? What is the problem you are having, what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: you can do almost everything in case of doing/trying to do it, not asking

Comment: @KevinSijbers how to convert a list as seen above to a much shorter list like the one below it. Eventually I would like to create a bar graph so I can see on each day how much of x,y,z there are.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Please show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your list is a list of lists with each sublist containing a date string and of of `x`, `y` or `z`, you can first group your list by dates.  Just create a dictionary, or [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), mapping dates to lists of x/z/y.

```
dates = collections.defaultdict(list)
for date, xyz in data:
    dates[date].append(xyz)
```

Next, you can create another dictionary, mapping each of those x/y/z lists to a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict:

```
counts = {date: collections.Counter(xyz) for date, xyz in dates.items()}
```

Afterwards, `counts` is this:

```
{'2-6-2017,': Counter({'z': 2, 'x': 1}), 
 '29-5-2017,': Counter({'x': 2, 'z': 1}), 
 '3-6-2017,': Counter({'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 1}), 
 '28-5-2017,': Counter({'y': 1}), 
 '1-6-2017,': Counter({'z': 2, 'y': 1}), 
 '4-6-2017,': Counter({'y': 1}), 
 '31-5-2017,': Counter({'y': 2, 'z': 1}), 
 '30-5-2017,': Counter({'z': 2, 'x': 1})}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Is there also a way to format this? So it is always x, then y, then z. And note a 0 if there is no x, y or z.

Like this:

 '1-6-2017,': Counter({'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'z': 2}), 
 '4-6-2017,': Counter({'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}), 

Excuse me for al these questions, I am very new a Python.